# Debugging a Maven Generated WAR

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, maven

Maven generated a WAR via an automated build, but then the WAR had to be manually tweaked so that an Apache/Tomcat combo on another computer could host the WAR.

The logs didn't provide much info, so I'm looking at the exploded WAR folder of a working WAR and non-working WAR.

Would you just use WinMerge (Mac OC Windiff-like tool) for reviewing the differences in the exploded WAR contents between the working and non-working WAR?

Is there something in particular that you'd look for in the non-working WAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had to do this before though in linux. I exploded both the war files out and did

```
$ diff --brief -r originalwebapp.war/ newwebapp.war/
```

This lists all the files that are different between the two archives. Hopefully, it will be a few files - most likely in the WEB-INF/ folder re: configuration of one form or another OR maybe libs being moved around.